# Openstack Magnum kube_master: Went to status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries

Tags: kubernetes, openstack

I tried to deploy a kubernetes cluster with one master node and one worker node in openstack magnum. But it returned an error:

> ResourceInError:
> resources.kube_masters.resources[0].resources.kube-master: Went to
> status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries.
> Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance
> c477d0d3-6176-4cec-b5aa-3a2fb7c77435. Last exception: Argument must be
> bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType', Code: 500"

Additional info:
Image used: Fedora-CoreOS 32
Flavor: 4VCPUs, 4GB RAM, 25GB disk
docker storage driver: devicemapper
docker volume size: 10GB

Nova logs:

> 2021-03-05 02:58:29.180 22 ERROR nova.scheduler.utils
> [req-aa6a7c8b-3d9a-4c8d-9d56-dfcb104ae828
> 53dd56f7fefc4bd38e2e4b1e8dde2b51 a67073edfee14079a6dda119969895c9 -
> default default] [instance: 8fd65139-c43e-40bd-836e-0ec57ea78960]
> Error from last host: kolla-ceph-compute17 (node
> kolla-ceph-compute17): ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '
> File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py",
> line 2437, in _build_and_run_instance\n
> block_device_info=block_device_info)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py",
> line 3550, in spawn\n    mdevs=mdevs)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py",
> line 6158, in _get_guest_xml\n    xml = conf.to_xml()\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 79, in to_xml\n    root = self.format_dom()\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 2726, in format_dom\n    self._format_devices(root)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 2680, in _format_devices\n
> devices.append(dev.format_dom())\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 1037, in format_dom\n    auth.set("username",
> self.auth_username)\n', '  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 815, in
> lxml.etree._Element.set\n', '  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line
> 593, in lxml.etree._setAttributeValue\n', '  File
> "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1525, in lxml.etree._utf8\n',
> "TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'\n",
> '\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception
> occurred:\n\n', 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py",
> line 2161, in _do_build_and_run_instance\n    filter_properties,
> request_spec)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py",
> line 2537, in _build_and_run_instance\n
> instance_uuid=instance.uuid, reason=six.text_type(e))\n',
> "nova.exception.RescheduledException: Build of instance
> 8fd65139-c43e-40bd-836e-0ec57ea78960 was re-scheduled: Argument must
> be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'\n"]
> 2021-03-05 02:59:08.970 20 ERROR nova.scheduler.utils
> [req-aa6a7c8b-3d9a-4c8d-9d56-dfcb104ae828
> 53dd56f7fefc4bd38e2e4b1e8dde2b51 a67073edfee14079a6dda119969895c9 -
> default default] [instance: 8fd65139-c43e-40bd-836e-0ec57ea78960]
> Error from last host: kolla-ceph-compute18 (node
> kolla-ceph-compute18): ['Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '
> File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py",
> line 2437, in _build_and_run_instance\n
> block_device_info=block_device_info)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py",
> line 3550, in spawn\n    mdevs=mdevs)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/driver.py",
> line 6158, in _get_guest_xml\n    xml = conf.to_xml()\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 79, in to_xml\n    root = self.format_dom()\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 2726, in format_dom\n    self._format_devices(root)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 2680, in _format_devices\n
> devices.append(dev.format_dom())\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/virt/libvirt/config.py",
> line 1037, in format_dom\n    auth.set("username",
> self.auth_username)\n', '  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 815, in
> lxml.etree._Element.set\n', '  File "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line
> 593, in lxml.etree._setAttributeValue\n', '  File
> "src/lxml/apihelpers.pxi", line 1525, in lxml.etree._utf8\n',
> "TypeError: Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'\n",
> '\nDuring handling of the above exception, another exception
> occurred:\n\n', 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py",
> line 2161, in _do_build_and_run_instance\n    filter_properties,
> request_spec)\n', '  File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nova/compute/manager.py",
> line 2537, in _build_and_run_instance\n
> instance_uuid=instance.uuid, reason=six.text_type(e))\n',
> "nova.exception.RescheduledException: Build of instance
> 8fd65139-c43e-40bd-836e-0ec57ea78960 was re-scheduled: Argument must
> be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'\n"] root@kolla-infra2:~# cat
> /var/log/kolla/magnum/*log | egrep -i "(2021-03-05).*error"

Magnum logs:

> 2021-03-05 02:18:26.681 19 ERROR
> magnum.drivers.heat.k8s_fedora_template_def
> [req-bc1f4cad-1636-42b4-ab80-f7e7c3459c5d - - - - -] Failed to load
> default keystone auth policy: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/etc/magnum/keystone_auth_default_policy.json'
> 2021-03-05 02:20:25.721 32 ERROR
> magnum.drivers.heat.k8s_fedora_template_def
> [req-4e8ac06c-debd-4980-9cbf-7a48684e75e1 - - - - -] Failed to load
> default keystone auth policy: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/etc/magnum/keystone_auth_default_policy.json'
> 2021-03-05 02:45:17.069 27 ERROR
> magnum.drivers.heat.k8s_fedora_template_def
> [req-205dd35a-5546-4919-875a-cfd15feeeadf - - - - -] Failed to load
> default keystone auth policy: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such
> file or directory: '/etc/magnum/keystone_auth_default_policy.json'
> 2021-03-05 03:00:00.418 6 ERROR magnum.drivers.heat.driver
> [req-17a7777b-0e70-4b8f-9199-026cd3f3d2ae - - - - -] Nodegroup error,
> stack status: CREATE_FAILED, stack_id:
> 1671e517-8227-47c3-9c7a-4642ececde33, reason: Resource CREATE failed:
> ResourceInError:
> resources.kube_masters.resources[0].resources.kube-master: Went to
> status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries.
> Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance
> c477d0d3-6176-4cec-b5aa-3a2fb7c77435. Last exception: Argument must be
> bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType', Code: 500" 2021-03-05 03:00:00.621 6
> ERROR magnum.drivers.heat.driver
> [req-17a7777b-0e70-4b8f-9199-026cd3f3d2ae - - - - -] Nodegroup error,
> stack status: CREATE_FAILED, stack_id:
> 1671e517-8227-47c3-9c7a-4642ececde33, reason: Resource CREATE failed:
> ResourceInError:
> resources.kube_masters.resources[0].resources.kube-master: Went to
> status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries.
> Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance
> c477d0d3-6176-4cec-b5aa-3a2fb7c77435. Last exception: Argument must be
> bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType', Code: 500"

Heat logs:

> 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR heat.engine.resource Traceback (most
> recent call last): 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/heat/engine/resource.py",
> line 920, in _action_recorder 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource     yield 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/heat/engine/resource.py",
> line 1033, in _do_action 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource     yield self.action_handler_task(action,
> args=handler_args) 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/heat/engine/scheduler.py",
> line 346, in wrapper 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource     step = next(subtask) 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270
> 21 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/heat/engine/resource.py",
> line 982, in action_handler_task 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource     done = check(handler_data) 2021-03-05
> 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR heat.engine.resource   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/heat/engine/resources/stack_resource.py",
> line 409, in check_create_complete 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource     return
> self._check_status_complete(self.CREATE) 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21
> ERROR heat.engine.resource   File
> "/var/lib/kolla/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/heat/engine/resources/stack_resource.py",
> line 463, in _check_status_complete 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21 ERROR
> heat.engine.resource     action=action) 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270 21
> ERROR heat.engine.resource heat.common.exception.ResourceFailure:
> ResourceInError: resources[0].resources.kube-master: Went to status
> ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of retries. Exceeded
> max scheduling attempts 3 for instance
> c477d0d3-6176-4cec-b5aa-3a2fb7c77435. Last exception: Argument must be
> bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType', Code: 500" 2021-03-05 02:59:49.270
> 21 ERROR heat.engine.resource  2021-03-05 02:59:49.291 21 INFO
> heat.engine.stack [req-9b34fa4a-da80-45aa-9596-6880e4a5d1ce - admin -
> default default] Stack CREATE FAILED
> (k8s-test-cluster-nyrxxu2pqvnj-kube_masters-5w5xewm2u4c3): Resource
> CREATE failed: ResourceInError: resources[0].resources.kube-master:
> Went to status ERROR due to "Message: Exceeded maximum number of
> retries. Exceeded max scheduling attempts 3 for instance
> c477d0d3-6176-4cec-b5aa-3a2fb7c77435. Last exception: Argument must be
> bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType', Code: 500"

Thank you.

Comment: `Argument must be bytes or unicode, got 'NoneType'` looks like a version mismatch of some of the involved software to me. Has this ever been successful? How was this cloud deployed?

Comment: openstack was deployed using kolla-ansible in multinode (3 nodes for controller, network, and monitoring, 17 nodes for storage and compute). we also integrate ceph storage in the cloud